# Queryset in Django if empty field returns all elements

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset

I want to do a filter in Django that uses form method.
If the user type de var it should query in the dataset that var, if it is left in blank to should bring all the elements.

How can I do that?

I am new in Django

```
if request.GET.get('Var'):
    Var = request.GET.get('Var')
else:
    Var = WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO FILTER ALL THE ELEMNTS IN THE CODE BELLOW

models.objects.filter(Var=Var)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a great idea from a security standpoint to allow users to input data directly into search terms (and should DEFINITELY not be done for raw SQL queries if you're using any of those.)

With that note in mind, you can take advantage of more dynamic filter creation using a dictionary syntax, or revise the queryset as it goes along:

**Option 1: Dictionary Syntax**

```
def my_view(request):
  query = {}
  if request.GET.get('Var'):
     query['Var'] = request.GET.get('Var')
  if request.GET.get('OtherVar'):
    query['OtherVar'] = request.GET.get('OtherVar')
  if request.GET.get('thirdVar'):
    # Say you wanted to add in some further processing
    thirdVar = request.GET.get('thirdVar')
    if int(thirdVar) > 10:
       query['thirdVar'] = 10
    else:
       query['thirdVar'] = int(thirdVar)
  if request.GET.get('lessthan'):
    lessthan = request.GET.get('lessthan')
    query['fieldname__lte'] = int(lessthan)
  results = MyModel.objects.filter(**query)
```

If nothing has been added to the query dictionary and it's empty, that'll be the equivalent of doing MyModel.objects.all()

My security note from above applies if you wanted to try to do something like this (which would be a bad idea):

```
MyModel.objects.filter(**request.GET)
```

Django has a good security track record, but this is less safe than anticipating the types of queries that your users will have. This could also be a huge issue if your schema is known to a malicious site user who could adapt their query syntax to make a heavy query along non-indexed fields.

**Option 2: Revising the Queryset**
Alternatively, you can start off with a queryset for everything and then filter accordingly

```
def my_view(request):
  results = MyModel.objects.all()
  if request.GET.get('Var'):
     results = results.filter(Var=request.GET.get('Var'))
  if request.GET.get('OtherVar'):
    results = results.filter(OtherVar=request.GET.get('OtherVar'))
  return results
```

Comment: Thanks Robert it worked perfectly.. In the first option how do I proceed if I want to set in just one of the variables to be greater then a number?

Comment: Glad to help! And regarding your question, you can change the query by altering the dictionary the same way you would any other dictionary, using conditionals. I made a thirdVar example in my example view, but feel free to let me know if you have a more particular use case that you're trying to build for.

Comment: Yes please I will need more help, I couldn´t reach.. The example is the following, the user is going to type a number on the form field and submit. The system should query and return all the elements with the number bellow that.

Comment: You can use __ syntax to access more complicated query functions. For example, say you needed to filter on the field "usercount" to find items with a usercount less than 10, you could do MyModel.objects.filter(usercount__lte=10) (lte stands for "less than or equal to"). I've created a 4th filter in my sample code

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert.. It worked!! Thanks for the help.. Best Regards

Comment: Hi Robert.. if you could help me I have another question considering your suggestion here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47371941/2-words-queryset-request-in-django-for-the-same-variable)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler and more explicit way of doing this would be:

```
if request.GET.get('Var'):
    data = models.objects.filter(Var=request.GET.get('Var'))
else:
    data = models.objects.all()
```