# 2 words queryset request in Django for the same variable

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset

If the user type "word1" in the form field of var1, I would like to do a query in the database considering the word1 + "word99"(as standard search), how can I do that considering my code bellow?

I am new in django.

Thanks a lot for the help

```
 def qrs_table(request):
    form = MyForm()
    query = {}
    if request.GET.get('Var1'):
        query['Var1'] = request.GET.get('Var1')
    if request.GET.get('Var2'):
        query['Var2'] = request.GET.get('Var2')

    results = Model.objects.filter(**query).distinct()
    qrs_table = MyTable(results)
    return render(request, 'app/page.html', {'form': form, 'qrs_table': qrs_table})
```

Comment: `query['Var1'] = request.GET.get('Var1') + 'word99'` not working?

Comment: hi schwobaseggl.. unfortunatly not.. do you have any other idea?

Comment: Schwobaseggl's suggestion seems right. Mind doing a few more things: 1) Post the HTML of the form that's submitting to this endpoint (i'm curious if the form field names match up) and 2) Add a print statement to the view so we can see what request.GET looks like for a request that has Var1 filled in.